# error: package org.springframework.boot does not exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin, spring-boot-starter

I keep facing the following errors for springboot in VS code:

```
error: cannot find symbol
@SpringBootApplication
 ^
  symbol: class SpringBootApplication
                SpringApplication.run(AdityaApplication.class, args);

error: package org.springframework.boot does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

error: cannot find symbol
@SpringBootApplication
 ^
  symbol: class SpringBootApplication
                SpringApplication.run(AdityaApplication.class, args);

error: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
```

I have followed the same steps for springboot on every tutorial but my code doesn't run

The following is the main code:

```java
package com.aditya.aditya;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AdityaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AdityaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.aditya</groupId>
    <artifactId>aditya</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>aditya</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What do I do?

I tried all different types of ways to setup and visited forums. But nobody seems to have a similar problem

Comment: I'm reporting another user's comment here, since they can't post comments: "Did you tried mvn clean install? Please provide the steps that you tried, when did the exception occure, when running the application?"